# It closes DIV on second click, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function which should close the div on click. However, it works on the second click. How can I avoid that ?

**JavaScript**

```
function showhide(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block') {
        e.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        e.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="foota123">
    Content
    <div onclick="showhide('foota123')" class="iks">X</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the initial style of `foota123`?

Comment: .mydiv { 
position:relative;z-index:115
 }

Comment: You're showing a regular JavaScript function but you've tagged the question with jQuery, so why don't you use jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

e.style refers to the style attribute of the div (style="..."). First time through, there is no style attribute on the div. The condition is false and the code sets a style attribute of:

```
<div style="display: block">
```

The second time through, the if condition is true, and the style of the block is set to "none". So it disappears.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `style="display:block"` ?

Answer (score 3):

Your code does not handles the computed style on the element, hence on first click the element is still in `display:block`.

Try this with jQuery:

```
function showhide(id) {
   $('#'+id).toggle();
}
```

[`$.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) will show the element if it is hidden else hide.

Answer (score 2):

The `style` property is empty by default; for example:

```
var e = document.createElement('div');
e.style.display; // ""
```

Simply reversing the condition should fix that:

```
function showhide(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.style.display = e.style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if you want straight javascript, the jQuery answer is better though :)

```js
function showhide(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(  e.style.display!=='none' )  e.style.display = 'none';
   else e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<div id="foota123">
Content
<div onclick="showhide('foota123')" class="iks">click me</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.
Html code

```
  <div id="foota123">
      Content
  </div>
  <div onclick="showhide('foota123')" class="iks">X</div>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function showhide(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);

if(e.style.display == 'block'){
  e.style.display = 'none';
}
else{
   e.style.display = 'block';
   }
}
 </script>
```

OR style="block" is also a better option.